# Add label to Gmail using IMAP, Python

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I'm trying to add a label to a subset of gmails. It's really buggy. It works, then doesn't work, then adds to the first email only...

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myaccountxyz@gmail.com', mypassword)

mail.select("my-folder") # finds emails with this label
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'all')

label_to_add = "label-to-add" # previously created in Gmail

for email_uid in data[0].split():
    result, data_single = mail.uid('fetch', email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data_single[0][1]
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    sender = email_message['From']
    
    mail.store(email_uid, '+X-GM-LABELS', '('+label_to_add+')')
    # also tried without the parenthesis
    mail.store(email_uid, '+X-GM-LABELS', label_to_add)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `mail.uid('search'...` you need to use `mail.uid('store', ...` otherwise you're mixing UIDs and MSNs (message sequence number) which don't correspond, so sometimes you get lucky and your UIDs happen to be low enough to hit an MSN.

Comment: Thank you! Full parameters are mail.uid('store', email_uid, '+X-GM-LABELS', '('+label_to_add+')')